# Is it legal to zero empty C++ classes in the constructor and inherit from them?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance, memset

It is not very rare to find a library that zeros its objects in the constructors using `memset`. And sometimes it happens to empty classes as well. Is it safe, especially when one inherits such classes?

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct A { char a; };

struct B {
  B() { std::memset( this, 0, sizeof(B) ); } 
};

struct C : A, B {};

static_assert( sizeof(C) == 1 );

int main() {
    std::cout << (int)C{ {1},  {} }.a
              << (int)C{ {1}, B{} }.a;
}
```

GCC prints here `00`, Clang prints `01` and MSVC prints `11` while emitting

> warning C4789: buffer '' of size 1 bytes will be overrun; 1 bytes will be written starting at offset 1

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jW1edecrd

Is it defined behavior? And if yes, which compiler is correct here?

Comment: If you use C++ correctly calling memset is (almost) never needed. WHAT are you trying to do? Even it this would be allowed (syntactically) I would stay away from it

Comment: Why? There is nothing to zero.

Comment: Note objects in C++ are not allowed to have size 0 when used on their own. So sizeof(B) will be 1 in the memset. This is to allow each instance of B to have a unique address. However C  doesn't have to have a size larger than 1 to work correctly.
So all in all your code is going to run into problems, again just don't use memset on memory occupied by classes. In general do not write code where you assume you know anything about the memory layout of a class!!! That is reserved for some very specific corner cases and then you really need to know what you are doing.

Comment: I think you just proved it is not safe. The zero size optimization that is performed on C assumes you don't access parts of B that are not directly accessible via members (but you are! you are overwriting the padding for some reason). As optimization is a compiler specific behavior allowed by the standard. This is not UB but rather compiler defined behavior where the compiler is allowed to do stuff that is not explicitly defined by the standard as long as it is documented by the compiler.

Comment: Since [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) has the precondition of [`std::is_trivially_copyably`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable), otherwise using `std::memset` on the object is **undefined behavior**.  Is your question constrained to that situation?

Comment: As soon as you add a virtual method, the warnings in clang and gcc will point out, that this is a very bad idea... https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hcxeGojGe

Comment: `std::memset(this, 0, sizeof(B) - std::is_empty_v<B>);`

Comment: "It is not very rare to find a library that zeros its objects in the constructors using memset." What code do you work in? My experience is the opposite.

Comment: If I remember correctly empty classes have a size of 1, unless its a base class in which case it since C++Something has had a size of zero.

Comment: @JeffGarrett, there is a lot of such code on [github](https://github.com/search?q=std%3A%3Amemset%28this%2C&type=code)

Comment: @Fedor Maybe, but is it(a) valid? (b) any fricking good?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is undefined.

The only objects for which you can copy bytes over them and the standard guarantees anything are objects of trivially copyable types which are not potentially overlapping subobjects ([ref](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types.general)):

> For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes making up the object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte. If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

> For two distinct objects obj1 and obj2 of trivially copyable type T, where neither obj1 nor obj2 is a potentially-overlapping subobject, if the underlying bytes making up obj1 are copied into obj2,29 obj2 shall subsequently hold the same value as obj1.

A potentially-overlapping subobject is ([ref](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#7)):

> A potentially-overlapping subobject is either:
>
> - a base class subobject, or
> - a non-static data member declared with the no_unique_address attribute.

So, according to the standard, this is not safe for any class usable as a base class.

It's also worth adding that this does not require an empty class to have overlapping storage in practice either:

```
class A {
    void* p;
    int a;
};

class B : A {
    int a;
};

static_assert(sizeof(A) == 16);
static_assert(sizeof(B) == 16);
```

B::a is stored in the tail padding for A on Linux. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GzEaYTd5c)